# Multiple different master-replication databases on one server

Tags: firebird, database-replication, firebird-4.0

I would like to know if it is possible to have multiple different master-slave replications on a single Firebird server.

That is, several masters on a Firebird server, replicating to their corresponding replicas on another server.

file - replication.conf:

```
#master side

database = /your/db.fdb
{
  journal_directory = /your/db/journal
  journal_archive_directory = /your/db/archive
  journal_archive_timeout = 10
}

database2 = /your/db2.fdb
{
  journal_directory = /your/db2/journal
  journal_archive_directory = /your/db2/archive
  journal_archive_timeout = 10
}
```

I already tried something like that. But it only recognizes one.

Comment: Simple "database" should be it. "database2" is naturally ignored as unrecognized section in contrast to databases.conf.

Comment: Or to rephrase user13964273's comment, you need to use `database = <path>` for **all** entries in replication.conf.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel In this case could you write it as the answer so it can be accepted, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by [user13964273](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13964273/user13964273), you need to use `database = <path>` for all entries in `replication.conf`.

It doesn't work like `databases.conf` where you create entries as `<alias> = <path>`, it is just plain `database = <path>` for each and every database you want to replicate.